# .Ignore() throwing exception after migration to EFCore 3.1

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity, ef-core-2.2, ef-core-3.1

I had this block of code working before migrate to EFcore 3.1 (using 2.2 before the migration) and now its throwing the following exeception: `'The type 'ProfileEnum' cannot be configured as non-owned because an owned entity type with the same name already exists.'`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfig());

     modelBuilder.Entity<ProfileEnum>()
            .Ignore(p => p.Name);
}
```

The scenario is: The ProfileEnum is a complex type that I map to User class using the following block

```
public class UserConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);

        builder.Property(x => x.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(200);

        builder.Property(x => x.DocumentNumber)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        **builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Profile, profile =>
        {
            profile.Property(c => c.Value)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnName("ProfileId")
            .HasColumnType("integer");
        });**
     }
 }


public class ProfileEnum
{
    public static ProfileEnum CompanyAdmin = new ProfileEnum(1, "CompanyAdmin");
    public static ProfileEnum Admin { get; } = new ProfileEnum(2, "Admin");
    public static ProfileEnum PowerUser { get; } = new ProfileEnum(3, "PowerUser");
    public static ProfileEnum Standard { get; } = new ProfileEnum(4, "Standard");
    private ProfileEnum(int val, string name)
    {
        Value = val;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ProfileEnum` type isn't complete, the properties are missing. But it's not clear to me how you're going to use this type. If EF can't set `Name` and the name/value combinations seem to be fixed, why is there a constructor containing `name`? Why don't you use a regular enum? BTW, the error is caused by `modelBuilder.Entity<ProfileEnum>()` which registers the type as entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up configuring the `.ignore(p => p.Name)` inside the entity mapping itself and the problem is gone

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);

    builder.Property(x => x.Name)
        .HasMaxLength(200);

    builder.Property(x => x.DocumentNumber)
        .HasMaxLength(50);

    builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Profile, profile =>
    {
        profile.Property(c => c.Value)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("ProfileId")
        .HasColumnType("integer");

        profile.Ignore(p => p.Name);
    });
 }
```